# Generating a list of 4-digit integers by simulating four dice being thrown eight times

Tags: expression-manipulation, digits

I simulate throwing four dice and merge their values together to form a 4-digit number. This is done eight times and I want to get a list like this one:

```
Dicethrowinglist = {3321, 2442, 5526, 3266, 5115, 2425, 5465, 4326}
```

I've done the following:

```
dice1 = {RandomInteger[{1, 6}]};
dice2 = {RandomInteger[{1, 6}]};
dice3 = {RandomInteger[{1, 6}]};
dice4 = {RandomInteger[{1, 6}]};
Join[dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4]
```

Which gives the output:

```
{3, 5, 5, 2}
```

However, I want the output to be 3552.

How should I change my code?

Comment: `FromDigits /@ RandomInteger[{1, 6}, {8, 4}]`

Comment: FromDigits@RandomChoice[Range@6, {4,1}]

Comment: With a twinkle of the eye: 'Fold[10*#1 + #2 &, 0, {3, 5, 5, 2}]' ;-)